# Header title and button do not vertical align JQM 1.4

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I have no idea why the vertical alignment doesn't work as in the demos. The title appears below the left button. I have tried JQM 1.4.3 & 1.4.5 same result.

```
 <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
     <a class="ui-btn-left ui-nodisc-icon ui-btn-inline ui-mini" href="#mypanel" 
     data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
     <h1 class="ui-title">Add Program</h1>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59XDP/47/

Answer (score 0):

It is because `.ui-title` is set to `display: block` which occupies a new row. Solution is to try `inline-block`

**CSS**

```
.custom-title {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 40%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h1 class="ui-title custom-title">Add Program</h1>
```

**Output:**

[image: Aligned Text]

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59XDP/47/)

I have used !important in JSfiddle, you make sure you load the Custom CSS afterwards to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set `text-align: center;` on the `div.header` element and `display: inline-block;` on the `h1.ui-title` element

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59XDP/49/))

```
.header {
    text-align: center;
}
.ui-title {
    display: inline-block;
}
```